# dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError {stack: (…), message: “Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined”}

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to get the overview map example working from here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_overviewmap.html

in my site.  I have two errors. Chrome gives the one above in the title and IE gives "dojo/parser::parse() errorTypeError: Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference".

Also Chrome gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when I have the OverviewMap variable in my function, IE says SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'byId'.   If I comment it out like this:

```
/*OverviewMap,*/ dom) {
```

and the reference to it below, I don't get those second two errors.

looked at this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86674/arcgis-api-for-javascript-error-in-dojo-parser-parse

I noticed that in my .cshtml file below, I don't have the Lang=en , but it was added into the HTML when I was looking at the console. So I added this:

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {       
        locale: 'en-us'
    };
</script>
```

but no change.

```
@model Site.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Map";

}
@functions{
    public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}



@if (1==1)
{
    @section toolbar {
        <li>
            <div id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" style="display:none">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="printSimple" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'esriPrintIcon', label:'Print'"></div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" id="measure" data-dojo-props="label:'Measure', iconClass:'esriMeasureIcon'"></div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomin"  data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoominIcon'">Zoom In</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomout" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomoutIcon'">Zoom Out</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomfullext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomfullextIcon'">Full Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomprev" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomprevIcon'">Prev Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomnext" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomnextIcon'">Next Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="pan" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'panIcon'">Pan</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="deactivate" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'deactivateIcon'">Deactivate</div>
                </div>
        </li>
        <!--        
        <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/identify_b.png")' />
        </li>
         <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/zoom_in_b.png")' />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/zoom_out_b.png")' />
        </li>
         <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/pan_b.png")' />
        </li>
      <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/global_b.png")' />
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src='@Href("~/Images/map/print_b.png")' />
        </li> -->
        }


    <div class="row-fluid" style="height:100%">
        <input id="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" value="@GetAntiForgeryToken()" />
        <div class="col col-lg-2 visible-desktop" >Sidebar</div>

     <!-- Bootstrap-map-js -->
        <div class="col col-lg-10">
                            <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
                    <div id="titlePane" data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Measurement', closable:'true', open:'false'">
                        <div id="measurementDiv"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div id="mapDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
                 data-dojo-props="region:'center'"
                 style="padding:0">

            </div>
       </div>

    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="todoList" id="loginPanel">
        <section id="localLoginPanel">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            @Html.Partial("_Login")
        </section>
        <section id="socialLoginPanel">
            <h2>Log in using another service</h2>
            @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
        <p>First time here? <a id="showRegister">Sign up</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="todoList" id="registerPanel">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        @Html.Partial("_Register")
        <p>Already signed up? <a id="showLogin">Log in</a></p>
    </div>
}
</div>

@if (1==1)
{


    @section styles {
      @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap/map/css")
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css"/>   


        }

    @section scripts {



        <!--
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/todo") -->


       <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>

<script>
    dojoConfig = {       
        locale: 'en-us'
    };
</script>


        <script>
            require(["esri/map", "application/bootstrapmap", "esri/toolbars/navigation",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dijit/Toolbar",
        "dijit/form/Button",
          "esri/SnappingManager",
          "esri/dijit/Measurement",
          "dojo/dom",

        "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
         "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
         "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
         "dijit/TitlePane",
         "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
         "dojo/domReady!",



            ],
            function (Map, BootstrapMap, Navigation, on, parser, registry, Toolbar, Button, SnappingManager, Measurement, OverviewMap, dom) {
              var map = BootstrapMap.create("mapDiv",{
                  basemap:"national-geographic",
                  center:[-122.45,37.77],
                  zoom:12,
                  autoResize: true
              });


              parser.parse();

              navToolbar = new Navigation(map);

              on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);
              registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
              });

              registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
              });

              registry.byId("zoomfullext").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();
              });

              registry.byId("zoomprev").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();
              });

              registry.byId("zoomnext").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();
              });

              registry.byId("pan").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.activate(Navigation.PAN);
              });

              registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function () {
                  navToolbar.deactivate();
              });

              $('#navToolbar').show();

              esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

               measurement = new Measurement({
                  map: map
              }, dom.byId("measurementDiv"));
              measurement.startup();

              registry.byId("measure").on("click", function () {
                  measurement.show();
              });

              function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {
                  $("#zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
                  $("#zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
              }

              var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
                  map: map,
                  visible: true
              });
              overviewMapDijit.startup();

          });
    </script>

    }
}
```

EDIT based on answer:

```
.
.
.
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
         "dojo/domReady!",
 ],
            function (Map, BootstrapMap, Navigation, on, parser, registry, Toolbar, Button, SnappingManager, Measurement, OverviewMap, dom) {
.
.
.
```

but didn't fix it

Answer (score 4):

remove lang="en" attribute from the HTML tag of the page

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you haven't got the Overview map in the same place in you list of requires and the associated list of variables.  Each module that is required is passed to the function and assigned to the variable name at the same index.  So, the first item in your require statement is "esri/map".  This will be passed to the first variable in the function definition which is: Map.  Therefore, Map is a reference to the esri/Map module.  Good so far.

Because some modules don't (always) need to be passed to a variable in the function definition, they just go at the end, e.g. you haven't got references for "dijit/TitlePane" and so on.  You therefore need to move the require for esri/dijit/OverviewMap higher up.  It needs to go in the same place as the variable name you are passing it to.  Put it between esri/dijit/Measurement and dojo/dom.

Hopefully that will solve the problem but if not, let me know.

Comment: good catch! but alas, it doesn't fix the problem, I have the same errors...
dojo/parser::parse() error 
TypeError
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function